# How to start a new count when the value of a categorical variable has changed in R

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr

Sample of mydataset

```
 datatrain=structure(list(DELT = c(10266L, 10266L, 10266L, 9635L, 9635L, 
    9635L, 10334L, 10334L, 10061L, 10061L, 10061L, 9512L, 9512L, 
    9512L, 10394L, 10394L, 9631L, 10376L, 10376L, 10376L, 10376L, 
    10046L, 9678L, 10332L, 10332L, 9985L, 9850L, 9850L, 10074L, 9746L, 
    9746L), EP_OBJECTID = c(86913544L, 86913544L, 86913544L, 86913544L, 
    86913544L, 86913544L, 86913544L, 86913544L, 86913544L, 86913544L, 
    86913544L, 86913544L, 86913544L, 86913544L, 86913544L, 86913544L, 
    86913544L, 86913544L, 86913544L, 86913544L, 90093693L, 90093693L, 
    90093693L, 90093693L, 90093693L, 90093693L, 90093693L, 90093693L, 
    90093693L, 90093693L, 90093693L), DELTDMR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 65L, 65L, 
    65L, 65L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -31L))
```

EP_OBJECTID is categorical variable. Here only two categories

```
86913544
90093693
```

how to set the sequence number from the first value of the category `86913544` to the last number before the new category `90093693`  in range 10000?
i.e. result

```
DELT    EP_OBJECTID DELTDMR
10000   86913544    0
20000   86913544    0
30000   86913544    0
40000   86913544    8
50000   86913544    8
60000   86913544    8
70000   86913544    0
80000   86913544    0
90000   86913544    2
100000  86913544    2
110000  86913544    2
120000  86913544    0
130000  86913544    0
140000  86913544    0
150000  86913544    0
160000  86913544    0
170000  86913544    0
180000  86913544    65
190000  86913544    65
200000  86913544    65
```

And how then to remove the last  value of category =`86913544` (= 65) which goes before the first value of the new category. In this example, the new category `90093693` also has a value of 65, but new  counting begin from second value of category `90093693`(=0). Also in range 10000

I.E. result

```
DELT    EP_OBJECTID DELTDMR
10000   86913544    0
20000   86913544    0
30000   86913544    0
40000   86913544    8
50000   86913544    8
60000   86913544    8
70000   86913544    0
80000   86913544    0
90000   86913544    2
100000  86913544    2
110000  86913544    2
120000  86913544    0
130000  86913544    0
140000  86913544    0
150000  86913544    0
160000  86913544    0
170000  86913544    0
180000  86913544    65
190000  86913544    65
200000  86913544    65
```

**10000 90093693    0**

```
20000   90093693    0
30000   90093693    0
40000   90093693    0
50000   90093693    0
60000   90093693    0
70000   90093693    0
80000   90093693    0
90000   90093693    3
100000  90093693    3
```

and this for each category.
How to perform it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the rows where `EP_OBJECTID` is not equal to previous value of `EP_OBJECTID` and `DELTDMR` is equal to previous value of `DELTDMR`. For each `EP_OBJECTID` create a sequence which starts at 10000 with a step of 10000.

```
library(dplyr)

datatrain %>%
  filter(!(EP_OBJECTID != lag(EP_OBJECTID) & DELTDMR == lag(DELTDMR))) %>%
  group_by(EP_OBJECTID) %>%
  mutate(DELT = seq(10000, length.out = n(), by = 10000))
```

This returns :

```
#     DELT EP_OBJECTID DELTDMR
#1   10000    86913544       0
#2   20000    86913544       0
#3   30000    86913544       8
#4   40000    86913544       8
#5   50000    86913544       8
#6   60000    86913544       0
#7   70000    86913544       0
#8   80000    86913544       2
#9   90000    86913544       2
#10 100000    86913544       2
#11 110000    86913544       0
#12 120000    86913544       0
#13 130000    86913544       0
#14 140000    86913544       0
#15 150000    86913544       0
#16 160000    86913544       0
#17 170000    86913544      65
#18 180000    86913544      65
#19 190000    86913544      65
#20  10000    90093693       0
#21  20000    90093693       0
#22  30000    90093693       0
#23  40000    90093693       0
#24  50000    90093693       0
#25  60000    90093693       0
#26  70000    90093693       0
#27  80000    90093693       0
#28  90000    90093693       3
#29 100000    90093693       3
```